# Swift error some return types are only available on macOS 10.12

Tags: swift

I have the following code however I am getting an error

```
some return types are only available in macOS 10.15.0 or newer
```

I do not want to add the @available on this. Is there a another way that I can restructure the follow code

```
public extension Action
{
    static var none: some Action { NoAction() }
    
    // -------------------------------------
    /** other code below
}
```

I have a struct in a different file
noAction.swift

```
public struct NoAction: Action
{
    public init() { }
    
    // -------------------------------------
    public var keyEquivalent: KeyEquivalent?
    {
        get { nil }
        set { }
    }
    
//other code same structure
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it notes, `some return types are only available in macOS 10.15.0 or newer`. So if you want to run on older versions, you cannot return a "some" type (i.e. an opaque type). You'll need to return a non-opaque type:

```
static var none: NoAction { NoAction() }
```

Alternately, you could return an existential type (i.e. a box around the protocol). That introduces some limitations on how it's used, but may match your needs:

```
static var none: Action { NoAction() }
```

Comment: hoping I am not asking to much but could you help me with this one
```
case .textCompletion:
                return (
                    #selector(NSTextView.toggleAutomaticTextCompletion(_:)),
                    .none
                )
```

Comment: I don't know what your question is here. I suggest asking it as a new question, with the relevant context.